# SharePoint 2013 Quick Edit while filtering hidden column shows error

Tags: 2013, hidden, quick-edit

I've got problem using quick edit while filtering by hidden column.

How to reproduce this error step by step:

1. For example in Documents add new column (I called it TestCol, simple text)
2. Add new element/document in list. Set value e.g. 1
3. Using AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=TestCol&FilterValue1=1 will sort all items in list by this column. Quick edit here works fine.
4. Hide this column (uncheck TestCol in Modify View).
5. Now in view use Quick Edit.
6. After changing name press Stop
   [image]
7. Error shows up, page doesn't redirect
   [image]
   [image]
8. After clicking on that list (for me Documents) changes are shown.

I check in Fiddler and it shows status 601.
Request looks like this

> POST /TeamSite1/_layouts/15/inplview.aspx?List={574CD88A-97AE-4315-BBA8-2802AB1AC0B3}&View={0136CAE6-365B-4F6D-BF49-6DC1F6C8250B}&ViewCount=0&IsXslView=TRUE&IsCSR=TRUE&FilterField1=TestCol&FilterValue1=1&FilterField2=undefined&FilterValue2=1 HTTP/1.1

As you can see it adds at the end

> &FilterField2=undefined&FilterValue2=1

In logs I found this:

> System.ArgumentException: Column 'undefined' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Where you able to display the filters back? I'm having the exact same issue here

Comment: Really don't remember right now. I always reload page after that and didn't notice any other problems than described.

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me - I manage to solve it by this scenario:

1. The list was connected to a query string url filter
2. The list webpart had 4 columns - one of the was "Program name"
3. The url filter - filtered the "Program name" column
4. In the webpart list view I removed the "Program name" from the view.
5. when I filtered the webpart by the querystring url and quick edit the list I got the error.
6. all I had to do is to add back the "Program name" field and that solved everything